# Yun's algorithm and integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, integers

Does [Yun's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_polynomial) work with polynomials which have integer coefficients and are not necessary monic?

Wikipedia says "polynomials over a field of characteristic 0" but this is what confuses me. I would say yes because I could add many ones and never reach zero but I thought integers form (are?) a ring, not a field.

Put differently, are those divisions in Yun's algorithm always realizable with plain integers? Are those division always "exact"?

Comment: Why do you think they would be?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I think it all depends whether those polynomials form a field of characteristic 0. But I never had abstract algebra so I seems to me that they should but I'm not sure. Maybe in order for a polynomial with integer coefficients to be a field it has to me monic, I don't know..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work for $\mathbb Z[x]$ because the steps in the algorithm deal purely with

1. GCDs, which exist in $\mathbb Z[x]$ because it is a unique factorization domain. Furthermore, elements have finite factorizations, so the algorithm can terminate.
2. divisions which are guaranteed to work, because you are dividing by divisors
3. differences between things in $\mathbb Z[x]$ and
4. we have that the formal derivative of something in $\mathbb Z[x]$ is also in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

You can't get around needing characteristic $0$ though.  Suppose the characteristic was $2$, for example, and look at what happens to $f(x)=x^2+x$.  The condition on the characteristic keeps information from being blown away by the formal derivative.

Comment: So to rephrase, I think Yun's algorithm should work for [] that happens to be a UFD with characteristic 0. Certainly this is the case when  is a characteristic 0 UFD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It works with polynomials over the integers (which is expressed with "polynomials over a field of characteristic 0").

The divisions in the algorithm are polynomial long divisions resulting in other polynomials, in this sense they are exact.

By the same token, the GCDs in the algorithm are polynomial GCDs returning polynomials.

(The polynomial GCD raises a little technical problem because the polynomial GCD is only unique up to a unit (+1 or -1), but that doesn't seem to be your question.).

Comment: *It works with polynomials over the integers (which is expressed with "polynomials over a field of characteristic 0").* That's not being expressed though: the integers *aren't* a field, so $\mathbb Z[x]$ isn't of that form... so something else needs to be said to qualify $\mathbb Z[x]$.